# How to check whether an array contain/include an object property in another array and also check if the input correspond JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, local-storage

From the correction you did for me, the initial question was resolved but the new issue is that, I want to firstly check that is what user enter correspond with what they register with which are at votersDetails && still found in the foundInAllElectionResult . If this condition is true, user be told you've performed this already.
Thank God, this first condition is perfectly working from the below code through the correction you told me to made.

Secondly, is to check what user enter does it correspond with what they register with at votersDetails && not found in the foundInAllElectionResult . If this is true, user should be allow to login and link to 'window.location.href = "e-voting-votingPage.html"';

At this condition, the condition does not work coz once the user enter what has not been set to the foundInAllElectionResult array, the code automatically allow them to login which i don't want.

and thirdly if user input hasn't been registered or found in the votersDetails array, and he's trying to login, he should be told to go and register first since he/she hasn't registered and the his/her entering details not found in votersDetails.

Lastly, if what user enter doesn't correspond with what he use to register which was set to the first array known as VotersDetails, (i mean his/her entered email and password ), then he/she be told incorrect login details. Please try again.

Thank you.

```
//This is the code that set their entering into the first localStorage at votersDetails. 

var votersDetails = [];
if (localStorage.localVoters) {
  var oldVoters = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("localVoters"));
  votersDetails = oldVoters;

}

function submitRegistration() {
  if (firstName.value == "") {
    firstName.style.borderColor = "red";
  } else {
    var voters = {
      fname: firstName.value,
      lname: lastName.value,
      email: email.value,
      password: pass.value,
    };
    votersDetails.push(voters);
   localStorage.setItem("localVoters", JSON.stringify(votersDetails));
  }
}


//This is the code that set into the localStorage at allElectionResult 

var allElectionResult = [];
if (localStorage.localResultsAll) {
  var oldAllResult = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("localResultsAll"));
  allElectionResult = oldAllResult;
}

function finish() {
    for (let index = 0; index < votersDetails.length; index++) {
      disp.innerHTML = `${votersDetails[index].fname}`;
      disp4.innerHTML = `${votersDetails[index].email}`;
    }
   
    var allVotersElectionResult = {
      name: disp.innerHTML,
      myEmail: disp4.innerHTML,
    };
    allElectionResult.push(allVotersElectionResult);
    localStorage.setItem("localResultsAll", JSON.stringify(allElectionResult));
    window.location.href = "final.html";
}


// This is the signIn function that I want to use to check all the conditions above from the new question 

function signIn() {
  var votersId = loginId.value;
  var votersKey = pass.value;
  var found = false;
  for (let index = 0; index < votersDetails.length; index++) {
    if (
      (votersDetails[index].id || votersDetails[index].email == votersId) &&
      votersDetails[index].key == votersKey
    ) {
      found = true;
      break;
    }
  }

  // logic to check whether the User entered email is in allElectionResult array
  let foundInAllElectionResult = false;
  for (let user of allElectionResult) {
    if (user.myEmail === votersId) {
      foundInAllElectionResult = true;
      break;
    }
  }

  if (found == true && foundInAllElectionResult) {
    warningAlert.innerHTML = `<i class="fas fa-warning" id="faWarning"></i> Operation Declined. <p>You cant vote twice, you've already voted.</p>`;
  } else if (found == true && !foundInAllElectionResult) {
    window.location.href = "e-voting-votingPage.html";
  } else if (found == false && !foundInAllElectionResult) {
    alert("please register, you've not register before");
  } else {
    alert("Incorrect details, Kindly please check what you enter and re-type");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the below `signIn` function

```
function signIn() {
  var votersId = loginId.value;
  var votersKey = pass.value;
  var found = false;
  for (let index = 0; index < votersDetails.length; index++) {
    if (
      (votersDetails[index].id || votersDetails[index].email == votersId) &&
      votersDetails[index].key == votersKey
    ) {
      found = true;
      break;
    }
  }

  // logic to check whether the User entered email is in allElectionResult array
  let foundInAllElectionResult = false;
  for(let user of allElectionResult) {
    if(user.myEmail === votersId) {
      foundInAllElectionResult = true;
      break;
    }
  }

  if (found == true && foundInAllElectionResult) {
    alert("Yes")
    //window.location.href = "e-voting-votingPage.html";
  } else if (found == true && (!foundInAllElectionResult)) {
    alert("No")
  } else {
    alert("Incorrect details, Kindly please check what you enter and re-type");
  }
}
```

`includes()` checks whether an **element** is present in the array or not, NOTE If you are searching a data in array of objects, you should not use `includes()`, you should do

1. Loop through the array to find the element.
2. If found, alter the flag variable, then check for that variable

You could also use array method like [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) and check whether the element is in array or not to achieve this.

Comment: Thank you for the response to my request. What i ask for though worked but an issue occurred from it.  All I want is that I want to firstly check that is what user enter correspond with what they register with && found in the foundInAllElectionResult . If this condition is true, user be told you've performed this already. Secondly, is to check what user enter does it correspond with what they register with && not found in the foundInAllElectionResult . If this is true, user should be able to login and third if the input hasn't registered, he should be told to register

Comment: Ok, from the functions you have specified in the question, I think you have to place this logic (you mentioned in above comment) inside the ```finish()```function. Read the registered users, ```localVoters``` from the local storage and you already have the ```localResultsAll``` from local storage in finish() function with the name as ```allElectionResult```, now do the same, initialise 2  flag variables, traverse the parsed data, perform the if..else logic (you mentioned above), place the ```window.location.href = "final.html";``` line as per your need,  Pls comment if you need help

Comment: Honestly I still don't get it. Can you please help me out. Have tried all i can as instructed but still don't work. I am still learning JavaScript. Thank you

Comment: Share the problem you are facing after making the changes, share with code so that I could help you.

Comment: function signIn() {
  var votersId = loginId.value;
  var votersKey = pass.value;
  var found = false;
  for (let index = 0; index < votersDetails.length; index++) {
    if (
      (votersDetails[index].id || votersDetails[index].email == votersId) &&
      votersDetails[index].key == votersKey
    ) {
      found = true;
      break;
    }
  }

Comment: // logic to check whether the User entered email is in allElectionResult array
  let foundInAllElectionResult = false;
  for (let user of allElectionResult) {
    if (user.myEmail === votersId) {
      foundInAllElectionResult = true;
      break;
    }
  }

Comment: if (found == true && foundInAllElectionResult) {
    warningAlert.innerHTML = `<i class="fas fa-warning" id="faWarning"></i> Operation Declined. <p>You cant vote twice, you've already voted.</p>`;
  } else if (found == true && !foundInAllElectionResult) {
    window.location.href = "e-voting-votingPage.html";
  } else if (found == false && !foundInAllElectionResult) {
    alert("re-type");
  } else {
    alert("Incorrect details, Kindly please check what you enter and re-type");
  }
}

Comment: The code above  has been what have been trying to do. I wanted to share all thee code at once but its too long than the max required

Comment: Add all your code by editing the question so that it will be more readable

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I'm going to do that straight away

Comment: I have edited the question. I don't know if you received the notification?

Comment: In your question 2nd para, you mentioned, "**not found** in the foundInAllElectionResult" and in 3rd para you mentioned that, "the condition does not work coz once the user enter what has **not been set to the foundInAllElectionResult** array", it works as per your requirement right ?

Comment: Yes. But the problem is when user enter a wrong details that is not found in the localStorage. The code still allow then to login which i don't want

Comment: Ok, then we have to check this condition ```(votersDetails[index].id || votersDetails[index].email == votersId) && votersDetails[index].key == votersKey```, is this correct  as per your requirement ? fields like ```id``` and ```key``` are not mentioned for a user in ```submitRegistration``` function.

Comment: Yes. The id and key are in the first array that's why they are not mentioned in the submitRegistration function. The only thing that was set into the second array is just the email and that's why email is to be checked in the submitRegistration

Comment: Let me explain more better in this way. 1. When user register and click register button which trigger the submitRegistration function , their fname, lname, email and password are set into a local storage on votersDetails array. 2. Once the user sign in by entering his email and password he registered with, he will be directed to a page where he will click finish button that triggered finish function and as he is clicking finish button, his email and fname was set into another localStorage in allElectionResult array. So what i want to archive is that

Comment: I want to firstly check that as user click sign in button, check whether the email and password he provides correspond with the one he use to register and if true, he should be allowed to login provided the email is not found in the second localStorage at allElectionResult, secondly, check if that email and password is correct, but if his email is found in the second localStorage at allElectionResult, tell him you can't vote again. Thirdly is to also check the email and the password he want to use to login, if both are not correspond with the one he registered with, he should be told to retry

Comment: Are you kinda busy?

Comment: I've sort the issue out myself. Thanks for the assistance

Comment: Hey, Good to hear that, Sorry I could not respond as I was stuck in an another work.

Answer (score 0):

Store the email which is entered by user into a variable.

```
let email = "langesh@gmail.com";
```

**Matching with votersDetails**

```
let foundEmailOnVotersDetails = votersDetails.find((voter) => {
  return email === voter.myEmail;
})
```

**Matching with allElectionResult**

```
let foundEmailOnElectionResult = allElectionResult.find((voter) => {
  return email === voter.email
})
```